# How do I handle an extremely late delivery?

Tags: software-development, clients, freelance

I took a client on in February for a mobile app. Another developer had built some infrastructure and I told them that I might try to save some of the infrastructure.

We made an agreement for certain features, including a style redesign.

Since that time, we had several meetings, the style design grew larger than I initially anticipated (I expected around the same complexity as the last design, instead it was more complicated). They've also been consistently adding new style requirements, like animations, new pages, new layouts, etc.

I also decided to integrate with a large part of the devops as it was enterprise level. I could have delivered a much smaller devops setup (I'm not a devops engineer), but I chose to try to preserve it as it would serve my clients long-term goals better. I don't feel I've communicated that well, as now the project is about two months late (due to the aforementioned stylistic parts, as well as this devops stuff).

My client is incensed. The app is late, and extremely so. But their employees have been asking for changes, and this devops stuff has just been a gigantic mountain of work for me. I finally finished it, but I had to learn Docker, Kubernetes, and an identity management system from scratch.

I realize that in the future I need to get an explicit contract with the exact features my client wants (we never discussed the exact server architecture or anything like that, and I'm not sure that the client understands enough to know whether or not this is valuable to him).

All I know is I am exhausted, I have worked extremely long hours over the past couple months and they're still angry. I haven't even billed since early April as I wanted to ship before billing.

I feel this is a combination of my and my client's fault (mostly mine), but how do I deal with them? Do I just say sorry and keep working? Try to explain what's happening and why things have taken so long? I'm working constantly on this and have been for months, and my client is extremely angry for non-delivery right now.

Comment: @Joe so, is the app currently finished? If so, what is preventing you from delivering it and put an end to this situation?

Comment: Yeah, it's a mixture of the new requirements, on top of the devops just being so absolutely complex. This was by far the hardest devops of any project I've ever worked on. I've had to basically learn a whole new profession just to deliver this to the same devops standard as the original app. I am thoroughly exhausted at this point.

Comment: @DarkCygnus a few changes, and up until now, the devops - I had to migrate an entire server cluster to a new domain with a bunch of new information. I had to learn a ton of devops technologies I am not familiar with. I finished that yesterday, so the rest of the delivery should be fine, but it's super late already, and I am extremely exhausted

Comment: Not to mention that I don't think they even understand the devops part, so who knows if they'll even pay me for this work

Comment: @JoeSmentz well they have to pay, you already did it and are about to deliver it. Be careful not to be scammed tho...

Comment: The [Freelancing SE](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/) might provide a more focused audience for this question.

Comment: @brhans - oh thank you, I didn't know that that SE existed

Comment: Yeah, I did a poor job of managing what they needed and also putting a stop to feature creep. I also did a poor job of communicating difficult technical things to my client. I have learned a lot from this failure

Comment: If it is any consolation, you are making the mistakes that others have made before you. I've had problems with both managing expectations and feature creep/changing requirements. Managing expectations is a people skill and I am still not very good at it. I address the gap with regular email and phone call communications. Saying NO to changing requirements is easier to address. You can throw in a few good will changes that are not too difficult. You should charge for the larger feature enhancements.

Comment: Yeah I didn’t mind a few changes, but when they’re upset because they app isn’t delivered and they’ve given a bunch of changes, and meanwhile I’m having the struggle of a lifetime with their server architecture - it’s just a lot. I’ve almost certainly burned this client at this point, but at least I learned a lesson about client management. This is my first large client - my others have been way smaller, my largest before this was usually a few thousand every few months

Answer (score 5):

> I feel this is a combination of my and my client's fault (mostly mine), but how do I deal with them? Do I just say sorry and keep working? Try to explain what's happening and why things have taken so long?

You say you already finished the app, so I suggest you deliver it and put an end to this stressful situation you were in, and move on.

Make sure you get paid the moment (if not before) you hand over the app (in future gigs, I suggest you ask for an initial payment at the beginning and then the rest at the end).

It is good that you realize that you have to be more explicit on the requirements, changes, etc., during development and designing. What you should do now is learn from this experience (which seems you already did) so you can do other future freelance projects more smoothly and without stress.

Comment: Oh, I'm going to be iron clad with my requirements going forward. "This is what you are paying for and no more"

Comment: What is also useful is to have periodic meetings with the stakeholders, where you expose the progress of the app. And yes, you have to be very firm on the allowed number of changes, the formal way of asking for those changes, etc., so this situation doesn't happen again

Comment: Yeah, it has devolved into them constantly asking for progress, while adding new features, while I try to work on the devops on the side which has been the huge mountain I’ve been dealing with. I should have presented them with saving the server architecture they had or making a simpler architecture, I should have made them wait for extra changes - they literally have asked for a number of material updates and acting as if they’re obvious, despite the fact that their initial design did not include them.

Comment: It’s mostly stressful dealing with the constant calls and emails when I’m literally working 12-14 hours a day and exhausting myself.

Comment: @JoeSmentz I am really sorry you experienced this... but, hey! you already finished :) I know you may feel burnout right now, so I also suggest you consider taking some days off after delivering this to cool down... and yes, all those things you learned you should do next time

Comment: If they pay me. I am worried they'll stiff me due to late delivery.

Comment: @JoeSmentz hmm... did you sign *anything* with this client? How did you agreed on the payments? Do you have anything to back you up? ... if you feel that such thing may happen (not getting payed) I strongly suggest you contact a Lawyer to assist you in case things go South

Comment: We had a contract that we agreed to via email, but we didn't sign anything with a set price for the app - which we are still pretty below. I've charged them $26k so far, whereas my initial estimate was for $75-100k. Biggest issue is that I haven't billed them since early April as it has been late, and I didn't want to push them too hard before delivery. But I do have this documentation and agreement via email that they agreed to it, so I THINK I should be ok.

Comment: At least from a legal perspective

Comment: @JoeSmentz the information you give me worries me a bit... now I suggest even stronger than before that you contact a Lawyer ASAP.

Comment: Ok. I'll contact a lawyer. I do have some leverage though - the app is under my Apple developer account, and I am the only person that has access to all of the code repositories

Comment: Good. Tread carefully here. Good luck with that Joe

Comment: Also how do I bill for the fact that the project is so late? Do I give them a discount? I mean, it has been a ton of extra effort on my part that was not expected, but it was also massively late.

Answer (score 4):

An additional, important piece here is to communicate clearly when new requirements are added (because there will always be gray areas in contracts). You can say something like:

> This requirement was not included in my original time estimate, and I will need to evaluate the effort required to fulfill it. Depending on the size, it may have to be deferred until a new agreement is reached or the original agreement is ammended to reflect a new timeframe and cost of development.

That's not the best wording, but my point is you need to let the client know that modifying the original request can both take longer and cost them more money. In my experience, the more upfront you are about this, the more likely both parties are to come to a happy agreement.

Answer (score 2):

Tell them how much is done and how much is remaining. Give a realistic estimate from today.

If they get angry, simply say that due to the changing requirements the scope got bigger and thus you haven't been able to deliver. If there's something else that's causing this delay, simply say that you're sorry and give a date.

It's also reasonable to be able to tell them which part of the delay is because of the altered scope of the work or unexpected problems that occurred. What does this mean for their cost?

Stop accepting new requirements. Only accept new requirements when the client understands what it will mean in terms of delay and added cost, assuming you have time for it to begin with.

Once the project is over you should research how to better anticipate the scope of such project, set an acceptable buffer for new requirements and so on (tell client what new requirements mean in terms of delay).

You should definitely get feedback from the already pointed out Freelance SE if you're not sure how to proceed, and there are numerous videos and articles on the matter that should help you navigate from here.